# How to use dynamic name for launch.json for flutter/dart in VSCode?

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

**The problem:**

If you don't have a launch.json in VSCode and is starting to debug/run flutter/dart program, it assign a dynamic name, for example, if you run for android emulator, then it will use emulator's name.

But, when you set up a new launch.json it requires a name (for example "Sample"). But if name will be provided the debugger will use incerement names like "Sample 1", "Sample 2".

**The question:**

Is it possible to setup launch configuration with the name, which will supports a dynamic naming?

My current config for example looks like:

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "front",
      "request": "launch",
      "type": "dart",
      "args": ["--web-port=3000"]
    }
  ]
}
```

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 1):

The dynamic name is assigned when a launch config has no name:

https://github.com/Dart-Code/Dart-Code/blob/2ff8cb91f6c5785069a33a36e0d33ef430809cf0/src/extension/providers/debug_config_provider.ts#L495-L505

This is the case when you don't have a launch configuration because VS Code just provides the extension an empty one. However if you create one in `launch.json` it needs a name so that it can be shown in the debug side bar drop-down (it cannot be dynamic here, because VS Code shows whatever is literally in the file).

It's possible we could support a substitution (eg. `${deviceName}` becomes the device name we're launching on), however it would show literally as `${deviceName}` in places like the debug side bar.

If that may still be useful, please file an issue requesting this at https://github.com/Dart-Code/Dart-Code.